# How to query for NOT trashed emails with Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I'm trying to create a script for Gmail to get only "NOT trashed" emails but I'm getting the thashed emails too.

Why?

```js
function fromGmailToDrive() {
    var query = "in:inbox -in:trash has:attachment";
    var threads = GmailApp.search(query);

    threads.forEach((t) => {
        const messages = t.getMessages()
        messages.forEach((m) => {
            console.log("m.isInTrash():", m.isInTrash()) //<- some are true, why?
        })
    })
}
```

That query is working if I use it in Gmail browser app.

Comment: try only `query = "-in:trash"`

Comment: I tried. It's the same, some `m.isInTrash()` are `true`, some `false`. It's driving me CRAZY!

Comment: If I use that query in Gmail it works! In the script nope. Why?

Comment: The same results I get with this query: `label:test AND -in:trash AND has:attachment`. Something is wrong I think...

Comment: I updated my answer. You should be checking for trashed threads and not for trashed messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated answer:

The method `isInTrash()` is supported for both [threads](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#isInTrash()) and [messages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#isInTrash()). In your solution you are checking for the trashed messages, not the trashed threads.

If you want to check whether a thread is trashed or not, you should apply the `isInTrash()` method on the **threads** instead:

```
function fromGmailToDrive() {
    var query = "-in:trash has:attachment";
    var threads = GmailApp.search(query);

    threads.forEach((t) => {
            console.log("m.isInTrash():", t.isInTrash());
    })
}
```

---

**Optional workaround**

Get all the [trashed threads](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getTrashThreads()) and exclude them (! [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)) from `threads`:

```
function fromGmailToDrive() {
    var query = "-in:trash has:attachment";
    var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
    var trashThreadsIDs = GmailApp.getTrashThreads().map(t=>t.getId());
    var clean_threads = threads.filter(t=>!trashThreadsIDs.includes(t.getId()));

    clean_threads.forEach((t) => {
        const messages = t.getMessages()
        messages.forEach((m) => {
            console.log("m.isInTrash():", m.isInTrash()) //<- some are true, why?
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: great workaround. I actually was able to recreate the issue once but when I deleted the main email on the thread under trash, I can't seem to do it again. My hunch was the main email on a threaded mail that was deleted was treated as trash but the threads following it weren't. The main email from the threaded email was deleted. but the threads following it was treated as not trash. Counting it as not trash and at the same time, trash. It confirmed the count of mails that have `isInTrash` returning true when I was testing it

Comment: @NaziA Thanks for your support and feedback. I actually think I understand what is the issue but of course the OP needs to verify that. Apparently you can trash both messages and threads. The OP is checking for  trashed messages but he should be checking for trashed threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now `clean_threads` is `[]` empty.

Comment: I have some messages in inbox and some in trash. Thread have them inside. So a thread can be trashed but also in inbox! What a mess!!!!

Comment: did you try the first part of the code? @user15308346 I updated the workaround but if the first script in my answer makes sense and answers your question, the workaround does not make sense to be used.

Answer (score 2):

As per Marios mentioned in the comment, you want to have `-in:trash`. But since you added `in:inbox` and `has:attachment`, it added those emails that meet those criteria as well.

If you want to find only the messages containing attachments and is not in trash, then use:

#### Code:

```
function fromGmailToDrive() {
    var query = "-in:trash has:attachment";
    var threads = GmailApp.search(query);

    threads.forEach((t) => {
        const messages = t.getMessages()
        messages.forEach((m) => {
            console.log("m.isInTrash():", m.isInTrash()) 
        })
    })
}
```

#### Note:

- You can also add `OR` or `AND` in between the query conditions/criteria to be explicit. Use them accordingly.

#### EDIT:

- If all else fails, you might just need to have a condition that checks when message is not in trash. This is not a good answer and should be considered last resort, but it will still solve your issue.

#### Code:

```
if (!m.isInTrash())
  // do something when message not in trash
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried. It's the same, some m.isInTrash() are true, some false. It's driving me CRAZY!

Comment: If I use that query in Gmail it works! In the script nope. Why?

Comment: The same results I get with this query: `label:test AND -in:trash AND has:attachment`. Something is wrong I think...

Comment: I'm not really sure now as to why it does that to you. It works on mine as expected. Can you show your whole script in the post? Is creating a condition where you check `if(!m.isInTrash()) // do something when not in trash` not applicable? If all else fails, maybe this would be your last resort.

Comment: I do not understand why it's working for you and for me not. It found some threads with some trashed emails and some not.

Comment: Hi @user15308346, it seems that some items in the trash that are showing numbers or multiple items are treated as trash but it actually returns true when `isInTrash()` is used.

Comment: Hi @user15308346, Sorry, I'm already unable to recreate the issue. You might want to use `if(!m.isInTrash)` for now, until you find the cause of the issue.

Comment: @user15308346 I realize this is many years in the future.  But check the "drafts"   In my case "-in:trash" is not enough because DRAFTS are not in trash but ARE in the SEARCH.

Comment: The reason that you see a difference may be that the gmail search box by default seems to exclude DRAFTS